# Name Extension based launcher for Mac

Tags: macos, applications, software-recommendation

Here is an example of what I need. I have a `.md` file (markdown). I use e.g. 3 MD-related applications: Sublime for more developer stuff; Ulysses for more writing stuff; Marked for viewing; Typed for short stories.

I would need an app that would give me a short beautiful menu of my apps I want to assign with the extension. In this case the workflow would be:

- Issue open command on a `md` file
- Since this app is registered as default handler, it popups and then
- I can choose quickly (by hitting the number, letter, or cursors) the menu option
- That is going to open the target application.

Is there such a 'opening-proxy' tool?

### EDIT

This tool should not depend on Finder.

Comment: Hazel is for folder monitoring. KM is for shortkeys - or at least I dont know how can I trigger a shortkey that is system-wide for file selected not only in Finder.

Comment: I do use Alfred, but dont know how can I trigger it on certain file. I am not using Finder much, but other file manager, hence I see this proxy as a program that is registered as default app for all extensions, and then I can fine-tune the apps that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot: [Magic Launch](http://www.oneperiodic.com/products/magiclaunch/). It does almost like what I ask, except you can't set more then one app per rule.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is [Alfred](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alfred/id405843582?mt=12#). There is a shortkey that popups Alfred window pre-populated with currently selected file. Then you can choose **Open With...** to choose which app you want to open file with.

Comment: [LaunchBar](https://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) is a similar tool to use the keyboard and search to choose which app receives the input you select via the tool.